# Kendo Template - Convert boolean value into yes or no

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-window

I have this kendo template and i am trying to convert the **isDiscount** boolean value into yes/no. Please suggest how can i perform this conversion.

```
 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
            <div id="details-container">
                <h2>#= Name # </h2>
                <em>#= Description #</em>
                <dl>
                  <dt>Price: #= kendo.toString(Price, "c")#</dt>                
                  <dt>Discount available: #= isDiscount #</dt>
                </dl>
            </div>
      </script>
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604605/kendo-grid-popup-with-yes-no-combo-for-boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional conversion inline like that:

```
<dt>Discount available: #if(isDiscount){# Yes#} else {# No#}#</dt>
```

There is also a demo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/uKohI)

Comment: I can see its working in your sample. But somehow it is throwing error in my code..

Comment: It is working now. I missed the # after No word. Thanks a ton.